# Google Invisible reCaptcha stalls trying to display challenge

Tags: asynchronous, invisible-recaptcha

I have implemented Google reCaptcha V2 (Invisible) on a site and it's being used to protect a login. The login request is sent to an authentication service via async which returns the success state etc.

The problem is, if a user fails the login on the first attempt AFTER their input has been verified by reCaptcha, on the subsequent attempt with any details it correctly hits the greCaptcha.execute() command but that's where it ends... for a couple of minutes at least.

During that period of 'missing seconds' the reCaptcha service appears to stall and my site ends up waiting for 500+ ms to get a response...

[image: reCaptcha stalling for 500+ ms.]

After ~2m reCaptcha suddenly responds with a bunch of resources loaded into the page which from the markup and resources found appears to be the expected reCaptcha challenge popup. While this popup doesn't actually appear, clicking login again continues as originally expected and the captcha is verified and login proceeds as normal.

[image: reCaptcha challenge tries to load but does not appear.]

If the result is a success the user is logged in and the site continues to operate as expected - even with other reCaptcha's on various forms etc.

If the user is unsuccessful... the stall occurs again... and again... until said user successfully logs in.

It's not a great user experience clearly, and there's no feedback or exception being returned, the request to reCaptcha.execute() just disappears into a void until reCaptcha responds 500ms later.

**Any ideas why reCaptcha is failing in this way?**

Answer (score 0):

Ugh... looks like the specific reCaptcha needs to be reset so the user can try to verify again. Pity there's no messaging to convey that fact, but it makes sense. Doh!

Will confirm shortly once I've investigated why reCaptcha Script is throwing a styling error in the console.

Comment: Confirmed. Need to reset related captcha element for re-verification.